# Are git pack files actually necessary on disk?

Tags: git

From my understanding, git SHA1 hashes had the side effect of reducing disk storage by not duplicating identical objects and zlib compression was introduced to explicitly reduce disk storage of repositories.  Later packs were added which introduced deltas to further reduce size and also grouped multiple objects in a single file in order to improve network transmission.

I get that the introduction of deltas reduces the size further and that grouping objects together in a single file might have some network improvements.

But is grouping the files together in a pack file actually necessary **on disk**?  I'm not sure what the benefit is, and it seems that it could cause performance issues during garbage collection because potentially large files might have to be re-written because of the pruning of an object (which I know is somewhat mitigated by putting large files first).

**I just don't see the benefit of actually grouping objects into a pack file.**  Is it to reduce the amount of chatter when negotiating which objects need to be transmitted?  If this is the case, it seems that the .idx file could "define" a virtual pack, but leave the actual objects individual files on the disk and only "pack" them on transmission.

I'm mainly wanting a better understanding of pack files and the reasons for them.  I have been working with a co-worker who has a problematic repository and understanding pack files is helping me help him.

CLARIFICATION:  My main question is not "why are pack files useful", it is: What is the benefit of storing the individual objects together in a pack file instead of having the index just point to individual files?  What benefit is there?  I only see the disadvantage of having to re-write pack files when objects are pruned.  I totally get the benefit of deltas.

MORE INFO:

More understanding on how pack files work and why:

1. Pack files are primarily optimized for network transmission,
   reducing the total size of the data being transmitted.  This seems
   to be the driving force behind the design decisions.
2. In order to reconstruct an object, *every* pack file must be searched
   until the object ID/hash is found.
3. Structure of the index files allows quick binary search, and the 
   index and pack file structures allow quick seeking to get the base and deltas
4. Pack files are self-contained which means a specific pack file must contain 
   the base file and any deltas necessary to construct a single object

So what I'm seeing is:

1. The fewer index files that need to be searched, the faster an object will be 
   found
2. Having the base and all deltas for related objects in a single OS file 
   improves performance of recreating an object by only opening one file 
   (for the actual data)
3. Every bit and byte counts for transmission over a network

I'm realizing through all of this that my main underlying concern is the size on disk of the pack files.  Extremely large disk files are more difficult to deal with in general -- both from a backup/restore perspective and from a content modification perspective.

The above 3 points I have observed don't necessitate, from what I am understanding, getting as many objects into an actual .pack file as possible.  I see the benefit of as many entries in a .idx file as possible to speed up finding an object, but I have a hunch the .pack files could be stored as multiple smaller files and still achieve the network and on-disk performance goals.   Even a scheme as simple as a single pack file per base and it's delta tree.  The existing index scheme could still group these together and keep the existing pack structure for transmission.

Anyway, I think I have answered my initial question with a bit more research, but have revealed what I was actually chewing on in the back of my head, and now it's a bit more into the hypothetical realm.

Comment: «git SHA1 hashes and zlib compression were originally introduced to reduce disk space of repos.» The only purpose of hashes is to uniquely identify objects in Git databases; the primary reason for this is to implement "content addressability" (Git was born merely as a so-called content-addressable filesystem, and it was envisioned back then that a VCS will be created _around_ it, not _in_ it); the fact this also allows for efficient storage is a byproduct which enables that "commits are full snapshots" paradigm to exist.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for the clarification.  I'll update that original statement.

Comment: For a discussion of why pack files are the way they are, look at the files in https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/technical and especially https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt .

Answer (score 1):

In general, grouping many small files into a single, big one typically increases the compression ratio, because you can usually find shared patterns in them.

It also may help reducing a lot of syscall overhead, which helps performance, specially in some operating systems.

Comment: From what I understand, it is the objects that are compressed, not the pack file.  I haven't dug into the source code, but reference: https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles

Answer (score 1):

Without pack files, Git isn't storing deltas at all. If you have a 100Kb file in one commit, then create a new commit that changes a single byte in that file, that commit *also* stores the 100Kb file in its entirety. `git show` simply "renders" the commit as a diff from the parent.

Pack files *literally* replace the copy the file with an actual diff, which means a checkout would require reconstructing the file, rather than simply copying it from the repository into your working directory.

Comment: I'm not asking why the deltas are necessary, but storing what's in the pack file as a single file.  Why not just have an .idx file that points to individual files that are currently stored in the pack file, whether it be individual deltified or undeltified files?  Then you would never have to re-write a pack file during pruning.  It's just adding/deleting individual files and re-writing the index.  The piece I am missing is:  Why are multiple objects stored in an individual file on the disk?  What is the benefit?

Comment: @MikeJansen: One benefit of putting packs in a single file is that you don’t need to read multiple files to get the data for a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Files have a constant storage overhead. It's been reduced about as far as practicable, so to whatever extent it's not negligible, it's necessary, so nobody much worries about it. It's generally at least hundreds of bytes.  Opening a file also has a cost -- the metadata has to be read, permissions have to be checked, current read positions have to be maintained. Either of those is, on the scale of individual objects and what delta compression gets you, a very heavy penalty to pay, far exceeding any compression benefits for small objects, and I'm not trying to be exhaustive here or paint a full picture.

Comment: ext4 for example stores file data in "blocks", each block is typically 4KB. So a 50-byte diff would occupy 4KB of disk space if stored as a separate file.

Comment: That does make sense especially with many smalls files.  A remedy could be having a single .idx file and having a limit to the pack file size, spilling over to another pack file if the limit is going to be reached (or putting a single base file or delta in its own pack file if its size exceeds the limit).  This would balance the overhead of the separate files with the size of the pack file.   A pack file size limit could be relatively large and still overcome the problems created by extremely large files.